# 1c:Предприятие зависает программ

Tags: 1с

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ЗадачаПортье(Команда)
  Перем МассивДней, КоличествоГостейПоДням, МаксимальныйДень, 
  МаксимальноеКоличество, i, ДеньПрибытия, ДеньОтъезда, День, пара;

  МассивДней = Новый Массив(1, 6, 2, 6, 2, 5, 3, 8, 3, 8, 4, 6, 5, 6);
  КоличествоГостейПоДням = Новый Соответствие;
  МаксимальныйДень = 0;
  МаксимальноеКоличество = 0;

  Для i = 0 По МассивДней.Количество() - 1  Цикл
      пара = МассивДней[i];
      ДеньПрибытия = пара[0];
      ДеньОтъезда = пара[1];

      Для День = ДеньПрибытия По ДеньОтъезда Цикл
          Если КоличествоГостейПоДням.Свойство(День) Тогда
              КоличествоГостейПоДням[День] = КоличествоГостейПоДням[День] + 1;
          Иначе
              КоличествоГостейПоДням[День] = 1;
          КонецЕсли;
      КонецЦикла;

      i = i + пара.Количество();
  КонецЦикла;

  Для Каждого пара Из КоличествоГостейПоДням Цикл
      Если пара.Значение > МаксимальноеКоличество Или (пара.Значение = МаксимальноеКоличество И пара.Ключ < МаксимальныйДень) Тогда
          МаксимальныйДень = пара.Ключ;
          МаксимальноеКоличество = пара.Значение;
      КонецЕсли;
  КонецЦикла;

  Сообщить("Отель: У погибшего альпиниста-1");
  Сообщить("Максимальная загрузка (чел.): " + МаксимальноеКоличество);
  Сообщить("Первый день с максимумом гостей: " + МаксимальныйДень);
КонецПроцедуры
```

Не понимаю почему при запуске вся программа зависает и все, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Для чего такой многомерный массив `Массив(1, 6, 2, 6, 2, 5, 3, 8, 3, 8, 4, 6, 5, 6)`? Все остальное тоже не правильно.